# WordPress Contact Form 7 Validation Not Working

Tags: wordpress

I am using class:required on my form fields but the validation is not working.

```
<div class="request-form animation" data-animation="fadeInRight">
    <h4>REQUEST AN ESTIMATE</h4>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 18px">Our estimates are free, professional and fair. Most estimates require a site visit. </div>
    [text Full Name class:input-custom class:input-full placeholder class:required "Name:"]
    [text Phone class:input-custom class:input-full placeholder class:required "Phone:"]
    [text E-mail class:input-custom class:input-full placeholder class:required "Email:"]
    [textarea Message class:input-custom class:input-full placeholder class:required "Message:"]
    [submit class:btn class:btn-light "SEND MESSAGE"]
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mising to add * after type of input.

To make a form field required in CF7, you have to add * after type of input.
eg.

```
[text* Full Name class:your-class placeholder "Name"]
```

So, just replace your code with below

```
<div class="request-form animation" data-animation="fadeInRight">
    <h4>REQUEST AN ESTIMATE</h4>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 18px">Our estimates are free, professional and fair. Most estimates require a site visit. </div>
    [text* Full Name class:input-custom class:input-full placeholder "Name:"]
    [text* Phone class:input-custom class:input-full placeholder "Phone:"]
    [text* E-mail class:input-custom class:input-full placeholder "Email:"]
    [textarea* Message class:input-custom class:input-full placeholder "Message:"]
[submit class:btn class:btn-light "SEND MESSAGE"]
```